# How to place texture across multiple edges?

Tags: mesh, texturing, faces

So I created this 3d model of a room in blender and everything went fine,
as I placed my initial texture which was the floor and it was perfect. and second texture was a wall texture which you can see below, and it was very much fine.

[image: It was still fine]

The texture was evenly placed as I wanted it to be. 
but when I placed the same exact wall texture on the part of the mesh with the multiple edges... the texture appears distorted and messy all of a sudden and looks nothing like the first wall I just textured.

[image]

what is going on here ? How do I fix this. Im an intermediate blender user and not that much of a pro yet. I know someone might know the answer to this .

Comment: It's because of bad UV Unwrap which is bad because of bad topology. You have a lot of ngons there. You can try Project from view unwrap or correct topology and go with Unwrap or Follow Active Quads even.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you need to [UV map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/introduction.html) your other face. This tells Blender what parts of the texture go where, so it can display it correctly.

I would press <kbd>Num3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num3</kbd> to align the view to the face (because it's parallel to the Y-axis) and, in Edit mode with all those faces selected, press <kbd>U</kbd> > Project from View (Bounds).